# Retrieving a set of rows from the sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

```
SELECT * FROM <TableName> WHERE <attribute(id)> IN <ArrayList type>
```

but theres an error

> 04-24 21:18:41.748:
>   ERROR/Error(29495):
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
>   no such table: 1: , while compiling:
>   SELECT * FROM Main WHERE id IN [1]

basically i want to select those rows with Attribute(id) which are present in an ArrayList...
but the format of the ArrayList is not the same as the one reqd for this type of query(i guess)
and i think this is the reason, its not workin correctly

if i query it with:

```
SELECT * FROM <TableName> WHERE <attribute(id)> IN <Integer>
```

it shows me the correct result... but obv it only selects that particular id's row...

note: ArrayList is replaced with Integer... (which is the data-type of my attribute(id))

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't see any problem with the Query (as Pseudo-Code) but can you post some Source Code on how you use the Query in Android. Also, notice that a Database-Query normally returns a Cursor, not an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no such thing as `IN <ArrayList type>`.**

You need to compute the enumerating string yourself by using JAVA code.

```
SELECT * FROM <TableName> WHERE _id IN ('1','2','3','4','5')
```

Also please note that on Android the primary key is recommended to be `_id` with underscore.

Comment: k
so how should i go abt it?
cause i dont know how many elements are there in the arraylist...

Comment: You just concat the elements as many times as there are, and you construct a string as long as you need. You need to build the string!

Answer (score 0):

When working with apps, I prefer to let the `List` I'm using to contain the elements it's holding like:

```
List<ElementType> = ...
```

By doing this, you can simply ask each element for their id's. Pentium10's solution will do the job, but I prefer doing this as it gives more flexibility.